# Extension functions cannot return null values

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I am using the below scripting functoid in the biztalk map to convert the string in to dateTime

```
public DateTime? ConvertOpenDate(string openDate)
{
    DateTime oDate;
    if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(openDate, "yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.fff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out oDate))
    {
         return null;
    }
    else
    {
         return oDate;
    }
}
```

But it is throwing error saying

> Extension functions cannot return null values.

How to handle this. I am inserting the datetime in to MS SQL DB

Comment: I can't reproduce your error with a quick test in LinqPad, but your date format string is wrong.  Use lowercase dd, not uppercase DD for a 2 digit day of the month: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#ddSpecifier

Comment: Hi all, this has nothing to do with using Extension Methods.  It's a simple date conversion.

Comment: have your datetime function return an empty-string when conversion-failed. In your map, check on the return value of the method. If it's not empty, map the datetime-field, if it's empty, just don't send the date element at all.

Answer (score 5):

This is known behavior: [Known issues in BizTalk Server 2013](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2954101/known-issues-in-biztalk-server-2013) with resolution "Return String.Empty or some other alternative value to represent the null scenario".

> Returning null is not supported
>
> Symptom
> When you return a null value from a functoid, the map fails and you receive the following generic error message...
>
> When you test the same map in Visual Studio, it provides a more descriptive error message:
> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. Extension functions cannot return null values.
>
> Note The XslCompiledTransform class does not support returning null values from functions that are called within the transform.
>
> Resolution
> Return String.Empty or some other alternative value to represent the null scenario. If it is needed, use a global variable to make the null value available across multiple functions.

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to prevent a null value to be mapped as input of your functoid.
This can be achieved by combining a LogicalExistence and Value mapping functoid (for delimited files) or IsNil and value mapping functoid (for positional files, because whitespaces are considered "existing" in that kind of files).